# Hiding password in headers using https

Tags: php

I can't seem to hide the passwords for a login form using https. When I view the headers, I see the password in plain text even though I am using encryption AND https. What am I doing wrong?

All I have is this:
form.html
 username
 password
 (using post, send to process.php)

process.php
$password = md5($_POST['password']);
echo $password; (echo's encrypted password, but in headers, I can see password in plain view)

Isn't ssl supposed to be secured???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SSL encrypts data as it's being sent from the server to the target computer.

Basically SSL protects your data from the rest of the internet not you and the computer issuing the request.

[Read up on how SSL works](http://www.verisign.com/ssl/ssl-information-center/how-ssl-security-works/)

Comment: This is correct--if you are using a client side tool such as FireBug or a server-side log to view the headers, then the password will appear in plain text because you are on one end of the encryption or the other.  If you were to try to put a "man-in-the-middle" and read the passwords there, you would find that the entire HTTP request is encrypted.

Comment: So in other words, even though I can see the password in my web browser, if Johny from Japan tries to sniff my password using http headers, provided I am using SSL, they WONT see plain text password right? I am seeing plain text because the http headers have already been unencrypted at my end? Is this right?

Comment: Exactamundo! SSL Basically makes sure the connection between the server and the client is a private one.

Comment: Which brings up another question: if I can see all sensitive info on my end, then how will I KNOW for sure that SSL is working?

Comment: I chuckled. Uhh this is an interesting question, if you have a router I guess you can use that and check the traffic being passed through it. Gonna return with an answer if I find something worth mentioning.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for all the help. I just found out you can use something called sslstrip to sniff ssl info as a middleman. Scary stuff, even info from banks! I guess if the hacker really wants to hack the website they will, and all the programmer can do is make it as difficult as possible to do so...sigh

Comment: Found a dude explaining the app, he used BackTrack Linux. Scary stuff. Well in the end, all security measures fail to someone determined enough, with enough resources and enough time... sslstrip. Sad times.

Comment: Wireshark on another computer on the network is another good way to see what's going on.